# Oracle Bpm integration/configuring with oracle jet

Tags: soa, oracle12c, jdeveloper, oracle-jet, oracle-bpm-suite

I created a UI using Oracle JET... and now how do I configure it with Oracle Bpm instead of loading a ADF it should load my own Oracle JET UI ... Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you still looking for help with this? I can share my project information which uses Oracle Web Forms (oracle jet using Oracle Cloud Integration)

Comment: still share that will help someone i too have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I think... It's very late to answer your question... when you deploy your process in WebLogic server, take the WSDL link, and  start writing restful web services so that your task is initiated with the help of the web service, Initiate the process through Web Service and then deploy the Web Service and Integrate the WSDL link with your Oracle JET and call it with Ajax call or RestAPI.